# How to handle 20k concurrent persistent connections

Tags: python, haproxy, long-polling

I'm trying to design an architecture to handle massive TCP socket connections and I'm in doubt on the limits of this architecture.

I'll have to handle **~20k concurrent** TCP connections and these are long-polling connections, they'll remain connected for **long periods of time** and will be sending data every minute.

Using threads is out of question, since 20k threads will starve the system resources. I'm planning to use **gevent** to handle such amount of **concurrent** connections or even use *haproxy* and 2 servers (w/ gevent) to handle 10k connections each for instance. Does that makes sense ? Does anyone have some advice or had some experience using **gevent** with 10K+ connections ? Does anyone have idea of the hardware requirements to handle these connections ? I saw [some benchmarks](https://github.com/ericmoritz/wsdemo) that shows lots of connection timeouts for gevent on 5k concurrent connections, what is not very promising for my problem.

**Note**: I've already read about the C10k problem and the advices on the "Million-user Comet Application".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use both at once in combination. Assign something on the order of 1,000 connections to a process. Use a [manager](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager) to distribute connections and spawn new processes if you reach a point where every current handling process is saturated.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you can use 2 servers to handle 10k each, why not use 5 servers and handle 4k on each?

Comment: What makes you think that if I can have 2 servers I can also have more than the double of this amount lol ?

Comment: because the hurdle of parallelising a task is between 1 and many.  If it is a case that you can't afford more than 2 servers then perhaps your effort:value ratio is a bit skewed?

Comment: @JamesRyan besides my utter amusement at pointing out that having two doesn't mean getting four, "Throw more hardware at it," isn't always the best answer, and sometimes it's a horrific answer. There's no reason a well-designed app can't handle keeping open 10k connections with modern processors and memory.

Comment: sure except he seems to want to handle them in python.  Throw more hardware is often a good idea if you pay for development time because the annual cost of an extra server is the same as only a couple of days. Particularly when you can get 90% of the optimisation done in the first 10% of the time, there is a point where struggling to get that extra little bit is not worth it.